# Add module into admin html in Magento

Tags: magento

I made a module `Filfact_Partners` in the local in `Magento`.
This module is a part in admin management.
Here is it's structure:

```
local
-----/Filfact
-------------/Partners
----------------------/Block
----------------------/Helper
----------------------/Model
----------------------/etc
----------------------/controllers
----------------------------------/Adminhtml
--------------------------------------------/PartnerController.php
```

At `config.xml` file, I added some code to menu:

```
<menu>
    <partners>
        <title>Partners</title>
        <sort_order>71</sort_order>
        <children>
            <partner module="partners">
                <title>Manage Partners</title>
                <action>adminhtml/partner</action>
            </partner>                
        </children>
    </partners>
</menu>
```

But when I request the url: `http://localhost/index.php/admin/partner/index`, it does not work.

So my question is: how can I request the above url, it will active: `controllers/adminhtml/PartnerController.php` controller.

If something is not clear, please ask me, all of your help are great things to me.

Comment: what do you mean on 'it does not work'? do you have errors? or a blank page? or what?

Answer (score 1):

You should configure routes for your module. In the config.xml file of yout module the following should be added (inside `config` node):

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Filfact_Partners before="Mage_Adminhtml">Filfact_Partners_Adminhtml</Filfact_Partners>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: Maybe incorrect controller class name? Must be `Filfact_Partners_Adminhtml_PartnerController`. And what do you mean on 'it does not work'? Do you have any error message?

Comment: I am sure that, this controller is correct. Please see this link about: [Filfact_Partners_Adminhtml_PartnerController](http://code.google.com/p/i-cuckoo-nest/source/browse/app/code/local/Filfact/Partners/controllers/Adminhtml/PartnerController.php?name=magento) at Google code host. You can see others file of this module.